# What is TLS SSL compatibility with jersey library in java 1.6?

Tags: java, ssl, jersey, tls1.2

I developed a client to communicate with a distant server using a jersey jackson library in java 1.6 (I am obligated to use this version). -- All is fine so far!

I was informed that the distant server is going to start using e a more recent TLS version to communicate. (now it is TLS V1.0 and the version that will be used is TLS V1.2).

What is the impact that this will have on my application (Taking into account that the operating system can handle a TLS V1.2)?

Remark: I use a simple WebResource to retrieve the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is platform dependent.  It depends on the JSSE your client JVM comes packaged with.

The JSSE is the Java Secure Sockets extension.  It is a pluggable component of the the JVM that provides the SSL/TLS support for your application.  I know the JSSE that comes with the Sun 1.6 JVM for Windows does not support TLS v1.2.  IBM's JSSE for their 1.6 JVM does support v1.2.

WRT to how this affects your application: that also depends.  If the only protocol your server supports is 1.2 then you must also have that support in your client's JVM/JSSE.  If the server will negotiate down to 1.1 then your 1.6 JVM/JSSE will most likely support that.

BTW it really doesn't have anything to do with the versions of Jersey/Jackson your app uses.  It really depends on the JVM the application is running on.

If your client app will run on a 1.7 or 1.8 JVM you will get TLS v1.2 support for free from the JVM without any code changes.  Also the newer VMs by default deactivate some insecure cipher suites that are enabled by default in most of the 1.6 JVMs out there

Comment: This is really helpful!! Thank you! My application is working on IBM's 1.6JVM. I checked to verify the TLS version with: SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactoryImpl();
SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) sf.createSocket(); 
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( s.getSupportedProtocols() )) ;

Output: [SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]

Comment: Can I suppose that my client app running on an IBM JVM 1.6 won't have a problem communicating with a server running on a JVM 1.8 with TLS V1.2 ?

Comment: TLS v1.2 is TLS v1.2 regardless of implementation.  I too would assume they will inter-operate but you need to test.  You should be ok.